# Java automation to keep triggering api until a result is met

Tags: java, api, polling

I have a question regarding triggering an api via Java until a condition is met.

I have the following code below.

String result= class.getID;

The response i want would be something like this

{"result": 1}

but the server takes too long and i keep getting this

{"result": 0}

I can do a Thread.sleep() but i dont want to do that since maybe it might even be longer.

Whats the best way of tackling this problem?
Can i add a condition where i trigger the same api nth number of times until i get the result i want.

Comment: As you are saying, server response is slow. So, I would suggest to track down why server is responding slow. Reason may be network problem. Or it may be some code. It is better you tell more about your server rather repeated call of API

Comment: That i something i can check, but im looking for more of a code solution.

Comment: It means your question is: How to make a repeated API call, unless desired result is got? right?

Comment: Yes by extracting the key and asserting the value possibly?

Comment: You can use a Timer for a simple solution or a ScheduledExecutorService, both will give you the possibility to query the server repeatedly.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example how i can add apis to ScheduledExecutorService? I did some googling and majority of them is just added a timer in seconds.